# What do I need to do to enable sFlow on my Cisco Nexus 9372PX?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, sflow

I have a pair of Cisco Nexus 9372PX switches running NXOS version 7.0(3)I1(3). According to the link at http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/7-x/system_management/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_7x/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_7x_chapter_011000.pdf, sFlow is supported on this switch and should be turned on using:

```
configure terminal
feature sflow
```

However, when I try this I get an error saying the command is invalid. When I run:

```
configure terminal
feature ?
```

... the sFlow feature isn't even listed!

I'm logged in as a network-admin user so don't believe this to be permissions related. Any thoughts on what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that NXOS version 7.0(3)I1(3) does not offer sFlow. We need to upgrade to 7.0(3)I2(1) for that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you check the prerequisites mentioned in that document:

> For Cisco Nexus 9332PQ, 9372PX, 9372TX, and 93120TX switches and for Cisco Nexus 9396PX, 9396TX, and 93128TX switches with the N9K-M6PQ or N9K-M12PQ generic expansion module (GEM), you must configure the sFlow and SPAN ACL TCAM region sizes for any uplink ports that are to be configured as an sFlow data source.To do so, use the `hardware access-list tcam region sflow` and `hardware access-list tcam region span` commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, the command "hardware access-list tcam region sflow" doesn't work either :(


switch1(config)# hardware access-list tcam region s

span   svi

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'logged in as network-admin'? What does `show privilege` say?

Comment: User name: admin
Current privilege level: -1
Feature privilege: Disabled

Comment: Well, there you have it: `Feature privilege: Disabled` indicates you can't enable new features, which is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I'm logged in with the most privileged user account (admin, which is a member of the network-admin role) on the system, and I can enable any other feature on the switch such as hsrp, dhcp, lacp, lldp - it's just that sFlow doesn't appear as a feature to enable.